# Create an Overlay on top of everything

Tags: java, android, screen, overlay, android-view

I am new to programming and have only made a few small apps for fun. I am trying to find out how to make an overlay on top of EVERYTHING on my Samsung S8 device (API version 26+).

What I want is to create something like the "Blue light filter" that already exists, however I want to change that filter to make it whatever I want. I am pretty sure I would know how to customise it and stuff like that. Currently the filter is orangey, what if I wanted to make it purple or black?

So my main issue is: I have no idea how to make an image, or a piece of text or anything, always be on top of everything that I do. I want to open up the app, change the filter colour, and for that filter to always be on, on top of any other app. I want to be able to minimise that app and for that filter to always stay. Can I call it a System Overlay or something like that?